# How to display MySql records in a table with multi-level headers in PHP. Dynamic Pivot Table in PHP using MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli

**How do I generate Dynamic Pivot table in PHP using MySqli**

I have records in MySql Database.  [Table structure is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mmGO.png)

Now, I want to display the records in a table with ***multi-level headers*.**, Like

[Multi-level table, how I want to display the record.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBF2k.png)

How do I solve this issue? Please help. Thanks in advance
I have found this code, but does not appear as I want.
    `<?php
    $output = array();
    $c=1;
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array( $res )) 
    {
      $output[$c]['headname'] = $result['headname'];
      $output[$c]['accyear'] = $result['accyear'];
      $output[$c]['fundamt'] = $result['fundamt'];
      $output[$c]['fundutiamt'] = $result['fundutiamt'];
          $c++;
    }
    ?>`

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th></th>
<?php
foreach ($output as $key => $html)
{
echo "<th>Solution ".$key."</th>";
}
?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Shipping Line</td>
<?php
foreach ($output as $key => $html)
{
echo "<td>".$html['accyear']."</td>";
}
?>
</tr>
<tr>

<?php
foreach ($output as $key => $html)
{
echo "<td>".$html['headname']."</td>";
}
?>
<td>POL</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: you'll need to fetch the records first, group the data accordingly (the array) then present it in html form, by the way where are your codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new array using the mysql result

```
    <?php
       $output = array();
       while($result = mysqli_fetch_array( $res )) 
       {
           $key=$result['accyear'];
           if(!array_key_exists($key,$output)){
               $output[$key]=array();
               array_push($output[$key],array(
                     $result['headcode'] =array(
                         "fundamt" =>  $result['fundamt'],
                         "fundutiamt" =>  $result['fundutiamt'],  
                     ) 
               ));
           }
       }
    ?>
    print_r($output);
```

Result

```
2019 => [ 061182 => [fundamt => 12, fundutiamt => 23] ]
        [ 961182 => [fundamt => 2, fundutiamt => 23] ]
```

You can use this array to make the table in HTML

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. It helps me a lot.

Comment: With the trail to your solution, I display the records in a table.

<?php
foreach ($output as $key => $html)
{
echo "<td colspan='3'>".$html['accyear']."</td>";
}
?>

Is this code okay ? Please help.

Comment: you will have to write two loops

Answer (score -1):

Use the colspan attribute.

```css
td,
th {
    border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
    padding: 10px;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}

th[scope="col"] {
    background-color: #696969;
    color: #fff;
}

th[scope="row"] {
    background-color: #d7d9f2;
}

caption {
    padding: 10px;
    caption-side: bottom;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: .8rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <caption>Alien football stars</caption>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Player</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan=2>Gloobles</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan=2>Za'taak</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">2016</th>
        <th scope="col">2017</th>
        <th scope="col">2016</th>
        <th scope="col">2017</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">TR-7</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>4,569</td>
              <td>7</td>
        <td>4,569</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Khiresh Odo</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>7,223</td>
              <td>7</td>
        <td>7,223</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Mia Oolong</th>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6,219</td>
              <td>9</td>
        <td>6,219</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(original table from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)

Comment: Sir, thanks for your reply. But want this solution in PHP. I can make it in HTML. But I want to fetch the record from MySql and display in in a table with Multi-level headers through PHP

Comment: I see. That wasn't clear from the question at the time I answered :) Glad you got your answer above.